# Not able to loop through tensors using Tensorflow in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops, tensorflow

I am trying to get the accuracy through function which uses the tensors of the output and the original values.

Here is the code for the loop:

```
@tf.function
def GetAccuracy(y, outputs):
    Accuracy = 0
    for Y_Value, Output_Value in zip(tf.unstack(y), tf.unstack(outputs)):
        len = len(Y_Value) - 3
        for i in range(0, len, 3):
            if Y_Value[i] > Y_Value[i + 3] and Output_Value[i] > Output_Value[i + 3]:
                Accuracy = Accuracy + 1

    return tf.div(Accuracy, 4.0)
    
Accuracy            = GetAccuracy(y, outputs)
```

And this is the error I am getting:

```
ValueError: in converted code:

    Train.py:100 GetAccuracy  *
        for Y_Value, Output_Value in zip(tf.unstack(y), tf.unstack(outputs)):
    C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\ops\array_ops.py:1322 unstack
        raise ValueError("Cannot infer num from shape %s" % value_shape)

    ValueError: Cannot infer num from shape (?, 120)
```

Please hep me resolve this and if there is a better way then please suggest me.

Comment: can you please explain how are you aiming to calculate accuracy? I don't quite get what you're trying to do

Comment: @AlbertoSinigaglia I am trying to get the accurate predictions. I have data where I am comparing if the exact comparison is found in the output then I am saying it is 1 means 100% for me. And there are total 120 value values and I have to compare them. After complete comparison I have divide the output by 4 to get the average accuracy of the total process. But I am failing to loop through the tensors. Please can you help me with this?

Comment: I need some informations, what are the shapes of  `y` and `outputs`?

Comment: if you just want a fix, remove the zip, use `range(tf.min(tf.shape(y)[0], tf.shape(outputs)[0]))` and use that index to go over the two arrays

Comment: @AlbertoSinigaglia The shape of both is (?, 120) where I have (1200 120).

Comment: @AlbertoSinigaglia I will try your suggestion.